# Why was the Shechinah bestowed upon Bil'am?

Tags: gentiles, rashi, nevua-prophecy, parashat-balak, evil-resha

In the beginning of Parashat Balak, Rashi writes:

> If you ask, “Why did God bestow His Shechinah on a wicked gentile?” [The answer is] so the nations should not have an excuse to say, “Had we had prophets we would have repented.” So He assigned them prophets, but they breached the [morally] accepted barrier, for at first they had refrained from immorality, but [Bil'am] advised them to offer themselves freely for prostitution." ([Bamidbar 22:5](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=45614&showrashi=true&p=1))

Nevertheless, the other nations could rebut saying, "Bil'am was a wicked man. If you had bestowed prophecy to a righteous gentile, we would have repented."

Why is this not a good counter claim?

Comment: And who says Bilaam wasn't a righteous man before he attained prophecy?

Comment: he doesn't have a good history. plus we see right in the beginning that he was greedy, honor seeking, and according to the midrash regularly had sexual relations with his mule.

Comment: Source? As far as I know, the Torah only introduces us to him _after_ he attained prophecy. I haven't seen a midrash with his origin story yet, but I'm open to seeing it.

Comment: @HodofHod when did he attain prophecy? after he was hired as balak's hitman or before?

Comment: Again, I don't know, it doesn't seem that the Torah explicitly says.

Comment: he did advise Pharaoh to murder all the jewish male babies. that was well b4 his prophecy

Comment: According to whom?